Qclass dose not generated(non-existent Qclass) witth Springboot3 + JDK17 + Gradle
spirngboot 3.3.1 + JDK17;
Problem occurred during migration from Springboot 2.7 to 3.3
my build.gradle.kts
enter image description hereplugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.5"
}

group = "back.ecommerce"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        setUrl("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:2.4.4")
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")


    // Logback Appender Discord
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25")
    implementation("com.github.napstr:logback-discord-appender:1.0.0")
    implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.3")

    //Auth JWT
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")

    //queryDSL
    implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0")
    annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0")
    annotationProcessor("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    annotationProcessor("jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api")


    //AOP
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")

    //AWS SQS
    implementation("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging")

    //Redis
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")

    //spring docs
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15")

    //webflux(REST API Client)
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")

    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
    testRuntimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

val querydslDir = file("build/generated/querydsl")

tasks.compileJava {
    options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory.set(querydslDir)
    doFirst {
        querydslDir.mkdirs()
    }
}

sourceSets["main"].java {
    srcDir("build/generated/querydsl")
}

enter image description here
To migrate to Springboot 3.0, I have newly written from gadle.build to gardle.build.kts
Because the existing entity code is Java code, we used annotationProcessor instead of KPAT plugin.
//queryDSL
implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0")
annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0")
annotationProcessor("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
annotationProcessor("jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api")

I expecting generated QClass

There are so many solutions to solve this problem.
I also have the same problem with you at exact same version of Java and Spring boot version.
Have you tried to check the version of JDK in your IDE?
Solution 1.

Press Ctrl + Alt + S and search gradle to check gradle configuration
check GradleJVM. It should be the same version with your JDK

Solution 2.

Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S and find project settings
check SDK at Project and Modules.  It should be the same version with your JDK

Solution 3.  (If you are Windows user)

If you use multiple versions of JDK, sometimes environment variable crushes with the JDK.
Set same JDK at environment variable

Solution 4.

Sometimes your git log has crush of it
Delete local brach having problem and checkout the branch again

I solved the problem with those kind of solutions.

Spring Boot 3+ based on Jakarta EE, so you should add classifier to querydsl-apt:
annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta")


I solved the problem that way. Thank you
